# SQL Table Changes Not Merged in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, merge

I have changeset "A" in my Stage branch that is about 4 changesets deep in history.

I recently checked in changesets B, C, and D into Stage and then did a merge of latest sources and deployment to the Release branch.

It picked up changesets B, C, and D, but not A.

I'm confused as to why this would happen because I selected latest sources, so it essentially is copying all of Stage and moving it into Release.

Answer (score 0):

Have you previously merged changeset A into Release?

One scenario I could think of that might cause this behavior, is if you previously merged A into Release.  Then manually reverted the changes from A in Release (via a new Release changeset).  Then subsequent merges from Stage -> Release will not bring over the A changes, because you have told TFS that you explicitly wanted to revert them in Release.

If that is what is happening then you should do a merge from Release -> Stage, then fix up Stage to look like you want, then merge Stage -> Release.